# About validates_uniqueness_of in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

i have a question, suppose that i have a model called Client, this model have a validation validates_uniqueness_of for attribute name, the problem is that the application is used by multiples users(use Client table), so lets say that a User 1 create a Client called Paul when other user try create a user with same same the validation will work, should however not.

I know if I did understand,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:scope` option:

> :scope - One or more columns by which to limit the scope of the
>   uniqueness constraint.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :user_id
end
```

Comment: if you want to scope it to more than one, use an array `:scope => [ :some_field, :some_other_field ]`